# Xamarin Forms UWP crash on start up

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, uwp

Debug output including stack trace:

GLLDBG Permissions check SUCCEEDED
...

GLLDBG: PetUI Displaying C:\Users\india\AppData\Local\Packages\0c046c82-7c9c-41e1-b7aa-0c1798833708_1d3xttr4xanc4\LocalState\photos\img676e113a6a9d41aa82bd2af2a6dc6631.jpg

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown at 0x76EAA892 (KernelBase.dll) in PetDiary.UWP.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80004003 : 'System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.SetCurrent(Page newPage, Boolean popping, Boolean modal, Action completedCallback)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__7_0(Object state)
at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContextBase.Invoker.InvokeCore()'.
onecore\com\combase\winrt\error\restrictederror.cpp(1016)\combase.dll!768325F0: (caller: 76795156) ReturnHr(1) tid(771c) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
Exception thrown at 0x76EAA892 (KernelBase.dll) in PetDiary.UWP.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80004003 : 'Value cannot be null.'.
onecore\com\combase\winrt\error\restrictederror.cpp(1016)\combase.dll!768325F0: (caller: 76795156) ReturnHr(2) tid(771c) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.

The crash ends up int the UnhandledException "handler" in the generated InitializeComponent function

```
        public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        if (_contentLoaded)
            return;

        _contentLoaded = true;
        DebugSettings.BindingFailed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            global::System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Message);
        };
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
                global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();  // <--- CRASH HERE!
        };
```

Any ideas? Does this look familiar? UWP is the bane of my existence... (I removed #if/#endif because the formatter complained)

Comment: I am afraid this is not enough info to go on. The error seems to originate somewhere within UWP, and tells us something was passed in somewhere as null, but it is hard to say what. From the Stack Trace it seems that this occurs during navigation. Can you provide some more relevant code, and ideally step through the debugger to see if you can spot something odd happening?

Comment: Nope! My app is starting up and the crash happens in low-level Windows system code to which I do not have source. I wouldn't even know where to set a breakpoint. The same code runs just fine on Android. I'll look at my navigation code to see if I can get a hint, thanks!

Comment: I also suggest checking Xamarin.Forms source code on GitHub to see where in `SetCurrent` method it could theoretically reach `ArgumentNullException`. In any case, please also report it as an issue on Xamarin.Forms GitHub, as they may be able to help or fix the problem, as it occurs on UWP but not on Android.